# Shared SSIS packages amongs Folders in SSISDB catalog

Tags: ssis, migration

I have two projects, ProjectA and ProjectB, that are being migrated to SSIS 2012. Both projects (before migration) used a shared project, ProjectC. 
What is the best way to deploy these projects to the SSISDB catalog? 
I dont want to copy the logic in both Folders of the catalog (as projects) because that would be redundant. Is creating a new Folder called ProjectC which A and B call the only way to go? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't the Project A, B, & C be under the same folder? You can control permission at the folder level in 2012 so if you want your users to access all three projects then this would be an option.